# Updating DNS record for my custom domain

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

Is there a way to update my customdomain DNS record to point to both the public ALB IP for my Kube cluster and also to the Gateway IP to route to *.mybluemix.net apps as well? I would like to switch the use of my custom domain to point to a CF app as well as a service on Kube cluster. Is this possible with the same DNS (A) record?

Answer (score 0):

You can list multiple IPs on a DNS (A) record. However, if you want to load balance across the IPs then you need to set up a DNS load balancer. Check with your DNS provider for more information.